# jQuery empty and html functions

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, spring

Hi I'm doing a validation on my server side and I return a JSON object with validation errors. Then the simple jQuery function writes the errors in a corresponding div :

```
function processEmail(data) {
    $("#newEmailError").html(data.newEmail);
    $("#newEmailVerificationError").html(data.newEmailVerification);
    $("#changeEmailMessage").html(data.success); 
}
```

That should work fine, but now I test my application and write some wrong email address and I got a correct error message. Everything looks right. But now I adjust my email and send form and should get only the success message, but I see both messages. It just looks like divs always got the last value if there is no corresponding message. I thought that for example, if the data.newEmail is null ( there is no validation error, and that object is null) the newEmailError div will get a null value = will be empty. But it just omits that. Now I have to write my function like this and use .empty()  :

```
function processEmail(data) {
    $("#newEmailError").empty();
    $("#newEmailVerificationError").empty();
    $("#changeEmailMessage").empty();
    $("#newEmailError").html(data.newEmail);
    $("#newEmailVerificationError").html(data.newEmailVerification);
    $("#changeEmailMessage").html(data.success); 
}
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem and not use the jQuery .empty() function?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could skip the `.empty` calls by using `||`:

```
function processEmail(data) {
    $("#newEmailError").html(data.newEmail || '');
    $("#newEmailVerificationError").html(data.newEmailVerification || '');
    $("#changeEmailMessage").html(data.success || ''); 
}
```

As you note in a comment, saying `.html(undefined)` doesn't do anything useful. And here's a little sandbox for experimenting with how [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/Html/) behaves:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/zgbnB/1/

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem with using empty, however, if you don't want to use empty, you can have your json return an empty string for the values you want to empty instead of returning nothing.

Alternatively, you can do this to condense it a bit:

```
$("#newEmailError, #newEmailVerificationError, #changeEmailMessage").empty();
```

Comment: It looks for me that this .empty() function is just unnecessary, but if it's a good solution I will use it :)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't actually know that, but apparently if you call `.html` passing a variable that is undefined then it just ignores it instead of clearing it.